# Is it always possible to row reduce any matrix to echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I was reading my Linear Algebra book and found this:

> 1. Reduce $A$ to an echelon form $U$ by a sequence of row replacement
>    operations, if possible.
> 2. Place entries in L such that the same sequence of row operations reduces L to I.
>
> Step 1 is not always possible, but when it is, the
> argument above shows that an LU factorization exists.

I want to know: when it's **not possible to row reduce** a matrix to an echelon form?

Comment: Are we considering only fields or could this be over an arbitrary ring?

Comment: What are "row replacement operations"?

Comment: If we're just looking at the $A=LU$ factorization, the key thing missing is the ability to permute rows. For example, if $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ then we cannot factor $A$ as $A=LU$.

Comment: Row replacement operations are row operations exepct row interchange. Steps 1 and 2 factor out A = LU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is regular and if you allow pivoting (see below) there always exists a LU decomposition:

$$PA = LU.$$

with $P$ being the product of pivot matrices, L being a lower-right triangle matrix with 1-elements on the diagonal, and $U$ an upper-right triangle matrix.

---

Pivoting is the process of searching for the maximum element in each column for the $i-th$ LU-step:

Find $k$, such that
$$|a_{ki}| = \max_{j≥i}|a_{ji}|.$$

The pivot matrix $P^{ki}$ then switches the $i$-th and $k$-th row. $P$ is simply the product of such matrices.

---

Pivoting also considers the case of $0$-elements on the diagonal, that might arise during the LU decomposition. E.g:

$$A=\pmatrix{1 &  4 & 2 \\ 2 & 8 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1} ⇒  A^{(1)} = \pmatrix{1 &  4 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & -3 \\ 0 & -2 & -1}$$

Here the pivot matrix needs to switch row 2 and 3: $$P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &  0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

edit: I forgot to mention: Since $A$ is supposed to be regular there will always be an element $|a_{ki}|\neq 0$.

Comment: I get what the author said. It's not possible to always row reduce a matrix by row operations **exepct row interchange**, otherwise there's an echelon form and we can achieve it by row operations.